# Convex quadrangles and their content

Tags: geometry

On the extensions, AB, BC, CD, DA of the convex quadrilateral ABCD are given points $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$, $D_1$, so that $|BB_1|=|AB|$, $|CC_1|=|BC|$, $|DD_1|=|DC|$ and $|AA_1|=|DA|$. Express the area of $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ in words of the area of ABCD.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The text is not clear: I think $B_1$ lies on ray $AB$, $C_1$ on ray $BC$, and so on. Is it so?

Comment: HINT: The area of triangle $BB_1C_1$ is twice the area of triangle $ABC$, and so on.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by that, could you explain it. Please.

Comment: Draw a sketch and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sketch that will illustrate the question :

[image]

Let us take the convention to place between brackets the (unsigned) area of a triangle, for example $[ABC]$ for area of triangle $\Delta ABC$ ; similar convention for the area of a quadrilateral, e.g. $[ABCD].$

Let us give two proofs :

**First proof,** using elementary geometry, which is an elaboration of the hint given by @Aretino.

One of the most basic formulas for the area of a triangle is :

$$\tfrac12 b \times h$$

where $b$ is the basis, and $h$ the height, for example, for triangle $\Delta  ABC$, we can take $b=AB$ and $h$ equal to the distance from third vertex $C$ to (whole) line $AB$.

Let us consider triangle $\Delta BB_1C$ : its baselength $BB_1$ is the same as the baselength $AB$ ; now, its height is twice the height of triangle $\Delta ABC$. Therefore, we have the first formula :

$$\begin{cases}[BB_1C_1]&=&2 \times [ABC]\\
[CC_1D_1]&=&2 \times [BCD]\\
[DD_1A_1]&=&2 \times [CDA]\\
[AA_1B_1]&=&2 \times [DAB]
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

The other formulas are deduced in the same way (please note the circular permutation of letters).

Now, if we add up all equations (1), we get

- on the LHS, the excess of area of quadrilateral $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ with respect to quadrilateral $ABCD$.
- on the RHS, $2 \times \underbrace{([ABC]+[CDA])}_{[ABCD]}+2 \times \underbrace{([BCD]+[DAB])}_{[ABCD]} \ = \ 4 \times [ABCD]$

Therefore :

> $$[A_1B_1C_1D_1]=5 \times [ABCD]\tag{2}$$

**Second proof** based on vectors and $\color{red}{oriented}$ areas:

Let us recall a formula for the area of a (convex) quadrilateral, not among the best known (see formula (3) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quadrilateral.html ; but I disagree on the clockwise orientation they give to their quadrilateral) :

$$[ABCD]=\tfrac12 \det(\vec{AC},\vec{BD})\tag{3}$$

and, of course, for the same reason:

$$ 2 \times [A_1B_1C_1D_1]=\det(\vec{A_1C_1},\vec{B_1D_1})$$
$$= \det(\vec{A_1D}+\vec{DB}+\vec{BC_1},\vec{B_1A}+\vec{AC}+\vec{CD_1})$$

$$=\det(2\vec{AD}+\vec{DB}+2\vec{BC},2\vec{BA}+\vec{AC}+2\vec{CD})$$

$$=\det(\vec{DB}+2\vec{u},\vec{AC}+2\vec{v}) \ \text{with} \ \begin{cases}\vec{u}:=\vec{AD}+\vec{BC}\\\vec{v}:=\vec{BA}+\vec{CD}\end{cases}$$

$$=\underbrace{\det(\vec{DB},\vec{AC})}_{+\det(\vec{AC},\vec{BD})=2[ABCD]}+2 \ \underbrace{\det(\vec{DB},\vec{v})}_{\color{red}{-2}[ABCD]}+2 \ \underbrace{\det(\vec{u},\vec{AC})}_{\color{red}{-2}[ABCD]}+4 \ \underbrace{\det(\vec{u},\vec{v})}_{4 \times [ABCD]}\tag{4}$$

(please note the minus signs in red).

finally giving

$2 \times [A_1B_1C_1D_1] \ = \ 10 \times [ABCD]$, i.e., again relationship (2).

Remark: I haven't given the computational details in (4). It suffices to say that they rely on relationships such as:

$$\text{oriented area of triangle} \ ABC \ = \ \det(\vec{AB},\vec{AC}), \ etc.$$

I end with a dynamic (artist ?) version of the first figure, figuring the evolution of quadrilateral $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ as its vertices take their time moving from their initial positions in $A,B,C,D$ resp. to their final position...

[image]